# nepomuk kioslaves

Tags: kde, nepomuk

I've been hunting the web lately to find some docs of the nepomuk kioslaves. So far, I found nothing useful. I even dug through the KDE SVN repo but couldn't find what I was looking for.

So far I know of `nepomuksearch: hasTag foo` (or something similar). But that's about it.

On the other hand: Is there a way to list all files that are *known* (not necessarily indexed) by nepomuk?

Answer (score 0):

The !kde group on http://identi.ca might have somebody who could point you in the right direction. There seem to be a number of people regularly posting messages about KDE things including nepomuk.

Comment: interesting... didn't know about identi.ca yet. I'll do some more digging.

Comment: It's basically an Open Source Twitter alike (with less features so far), there seems to be quite a lot of Linux stuff on there. The software behind it is called status.net is open source and can be installed to your own server to make your own microblogging site.

Answer (score -4):

Does this helps you?

http://osdir.com/ml/kde-commits/2009-08/msg01696.html

One of the first results when googling. Im not familiar with it, but doing a search on Google isn't that hard, is it? Get the right keywords man.

Comment: Google it is not an acceptable answer on SU. Google is the SU home page.

Comment: Telling people to google for their answer is not helpful.  At the very least, why don't you share which keywords you used to get the answer, since coming up witht he right keywords can sometimes be difficult if you are unfamiliar with the problem domain.

Comment: Nothing is more irritating than coming up against result after result of "Google it" when searching for answers.

Comment: I actually found this already. Yes, beleive it or not: I googled before coming here! And no, it doesn't helps me ;)